# Remove single br in paragraph but not double br?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a paragraph with some single `<br>` and double `<br>`.

I'd like to add all the single `<br>`, but not the double `<br>`.

How is that possible?

If I use

```
p br {display:none}
```

It hides all the br tags. However, when I have two br, I would like them to still display . . ..  How can we make this work? It seems I can not find any relevant information.

I also tried the following without success:

```
p br { content: ' '; }
```

Thanks a lot for your time !

-- edit --

my paragraph is formatted like that:

```
<p> oremipsum lorem<br/>
orem blalgr<br/><br/>
loremg grthrt
</p>
```

Comment: this is not possible with pure css you have to use javascript for this Normally I put class on this case `<br class="hide-on-mobile>"`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, if you want to show two `<br />` but remove one, then it's simple. You can use `+` next-child selector:

```css
p {margin: 0;}
br {display: none;}
br + br {display: block; margin-bottom: 2em;}
```

```html
<p>Hello. One BR below.</p>
<br />
<p>Hello. Two BR below.</p>
<br /><br />
<p>Hello. One BR below.</p>
<br />
<p>Hello. Two BR below.</p>
<br /><br />
<p>Hello. No BR below.</p>
```

Comment: This will hide the first of the two `br`s: `<br/><br/>` will look like single `<br/>`, since the first will be hidden.

Comment: @Arg0n Yea, that's why I have added the `margin-bottom: 2em` to make it look like there are two `<br />`s. If the OP comes back, I am happy to change it to their needs. Doesn't it work now? It works for me in my browser. ☺

Comment: Nope, does not look the same as my result with the `<br/><br/>` intact.

Comment: Your answer will fail when there are more than two <br>'s. Better would be  `p + br { display:...}` which will only display the first <br>. BUT according to OP you should use one <p> with several <br>'s

Comment: Thank you guys, but non is working . ..  i have added the way my paragraph is formatted . .. . the single and double br are within the same <p> ...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I agree with your logic. Now OP should clarify a lot of questions. **1.** Will there be more than two `<br />`s? **2.** What should be two `<br />`s be converted to?

Comment: @thebigE Nice that you are here. Okay, can you draw and tell us, what should happen with one `<br />` and two `<br />`s? Also, answer the two questions I asked in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar, one there is only one '<br/>', it should not display. But if there is 2 '<br/>' , both of them should display ( to look like starting one paragraph). Hope that make sense ?

I tried your css, without success .. . 

Really appreciate your time !

Comment: @thebigE "Without success", okay, so what's not working? What do you see? How do you expect it?

Comment: single <br/> is not being hidden . . .

Im expeting to have the isngel br to be hidden ( display none0 and double to be still display

Comment: @thebigE What do you mean by hidden, do you want them to be on a same line?

Comment: exact, yes:) to not have a breakline when only one <br/>is use

Comment: @thebigE Perfect... Give me a moment.

Comment: @thebigE http://jsbin.com/zogojumaci/edit?html,css,output Does this work?

Comment: no .. .  I may have something overwritting  i ll check it !

Comment: that work for the first br, but If i have multiple br in the pararaph, it doesn't hide the one following .. .

Comment: This is becomming a guessing game. Time to add an example of how a row of <p>'s should look like, thebigE, in plain text, of course.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Agreed... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery will remove any single `<br/>`, but still keep `<br/><br/>`:

```js
$(".container br").filter(function() {
  var $item = $(this);
  return !$item.next().is("br") && !$item.prev().is("br");
}).remove();
```

```css
p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello. One BR below.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Hello. Two BR below.</p>
  <br /><br />
  <p>Hello. One BR below.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Hello. Two BR below.</p>
  <br /><br />
  <p>Hello. No BR below.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other contents of the `p` is just text, you can replace all single `br` using regular expressions:

```js
var $p = $("p");
console.log($p.html());
$p.html($p.html().replace(/(\s*[^>\s]\s*)<br>\s*(?!\s*<br>)/gi, '$1'));
console.log($p.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  oremipsum lorem    <br/> 
  orem blalgr <br/>  <br/> 
  loremg grthrt
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Arg0N, but non is working . ..  i have added the way my paragraph is formatted . .. . the single and double br are within the same <p> ...

Comment: @thebigE Updated with your HTML (a bit modified to adapt to whitespaces also). You can remove the `console.log`s btw.

Comment: arf, Thanks for this, but it makes appaer some other paragraph  somehow and unformatting everything . .  no idea why :/

Answer (score -1):

You only need this CSS:

```
br + br { display:none; }
```

Comment: Thank you Calvin, but non is working . ..  i have added the way my paragraph is formatted . .. . the single and double br are within the same <p> ...

Comment: Try to use Javascript instead. brbr=document.querySelector ('br + br'); brbr.style.display = 'none'; ... www.jsfiddle.net/x1L1xruj/